# Может ли работать Bootstrap с view.php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Можно ли подключить Bootstrap к php что бы оформить view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

очень долго искал в гугле, перерыл все форумы но нашел ответ на ваш вопрос

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Поле ответа предназначено только для конечных ответов на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению.